# Testing cocos2d iPhone using Calabash-iOS

Tags: unit-testing, cocos2d-iphone, calabash

Some people suggested https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios for iOS tests. I am using cocos2d-iphone, can I write tests for it using calabash?

Still calabash turned me off because it says it will only work with the simulator which is not enough and also if devices I have to use a service which just sounds like trouble. Any clean solution?

> After completing this guide you will be able to run tests locally
>   against the iOS Simulator. You can also interactively explore and
>   interact with your application using the Calabash console.
>
> Finally, you will be able to test your app on real, non-jailbroken iOS
>   devices via the LessPainful service.

Edit: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/07-Testing-on-physical-iDevices suggests that device testing is possible... I guess I'll just have to try it myself...

Edit 2: I did get it all working. Even hooking up to a remote device that is not even plugged into the computer (just needs to be on same WIFI). When hooking up to the device it helps using the UDID of the device, this was not stated on calabash-ios docs, or I missed that.
For anyone coming here later, this is the final command that will work:

```
DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://192.168.36.180:37265 BUNDLE_ID=build/tabeyou-cal DEVICE_TARGET=thelongudidofyourdevicegoeshere OS=ios6 cucumber
```

Just replace the ip to the ip of your device, the udid, and BUNDLE_ID which should be the target name (I think).

My current question is, how would I identify cocos2d stuff like CCMenu, CCSprite etc? These all seem to support accessibility identifiers and I'm sure the Ruby-iOS part could find anything under the hood - in turn that should make it possible to write tests interacting with cocos2d elements.

Comment: what's wrong with Xcode's built-in unit testing framework? Works fine with cocos2d.

Comment: I will try that too. I got Calabash-iOS working without too much trouble. https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/07-Testing-on-physical-iDevices Calabash uses a very interesting set of technologies like the Gherkin language which is just fun on its own.

Comment: Do you want to do unit testing or have fun? ;)

Comment: After looking at Xcode's built-in unit testing framework - there really isn't any support for testing the GUI now is there? You can do some of it with Instruments but as that path only supports UIKit really, it, like calabash-ios, leaves us out in the cold because we use cocos2d, or any other game engine and none of that is supported. If I had more time I'd try to extend calabash-ios to do that. I think it can be done, with a little time and some perspiration. The goal would be to have tests play games through to the end on real device and make sure no bugs appear along the way.